# Como mapear entidade com hibernate para criar constraints non-unique?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou tentando criar uma entidade com o seguinte mapeamento:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AutenticacaoPK.class)
public class Autenticacao {

  @Id
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "codUsuario", unique = false)
  private Usuario usuario;

  @Id
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "codEmpresa", unique = false)
  private Empresa empresa;

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, length = 1000)
  private String token;
}
```

E no banco de dados a tabela ficou da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE autenticacao(
 token character varying(1000) NOT NULL,
 codusuario bigint NOT NULL,
 codempresa bigint NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT autenticacao_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codempresa, token, codusuario),
CONSTRAINT fk_92assff1b6x84mm97rlb7jl7m FOREIGN KEY (codusuario)
 REFERENCES usuario (codusuario) MATCH SIMPLE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT fk_hb45dbp517t2eyghrwfo4ktqh FOREIGN KEY (codempresa)
 REFERENCES empresa (codempresa) MATCH SIMPLE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT uk_92assff1b6x84mm97rlb7jl7m UNIQUE (codusuario),// NAO CRIAR
CONSTRAINT uk_hb45dbp517t2eyghrwfo4ktqh UNIQUE (codempresa))// NAO CRIAR
```

Problema é que está sendo criado as constraint UNIQUE (codusuario) e UNIQUE (codempresa).
A constraint que queria criar era somente para que as três colunas não se repetissem e as Foreign.
Mesmo colocando "unique=false" as constraint mencionadas foram criadas.

**Atualização**

A classe AutenticacaoPK:

```
 public class AutenticacaoPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6769917015564615074L;
    protected Usuario usuario;
    protected Empresa empresa;
    protected String token;

    public AutenticacaoPK(Usuario usuario, Empresa empresa, String token) {
       this.empresa = empresa;
       this.token = token;
       this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    AutenticacaoPK() {}
}
```

Comment: Como está sua classe `AutenticacaoPK`?

Comment: `public class AutenticacaoPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6769917015564615074L;
    protected Usuario usuario;
    protected Empresa empresa;
    protected String token;

    public AutenticacaoPK(Usuario usuario, Empresa empresa, Stringtoken) {
this.empresa = empresa;
this.token= token;
this.usuario = usuario;
}
AutenticacaoPK() {}}` @VictorStafusa

Answer (score 2):

Acabei mapeando de outra forma e consegui o que queria (parcialmente).

```
@Entity
//@IdClass(AutenticacaoPK.class)
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"codEmpresa", "codUsuario"}))
public class AutenticacaoMobile {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "codUsuario", unique = false)
  private Usuario usuario;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "codEmpresa", unique = false)
  private Empresa empresa;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 1000)
private String token;
```

Retirei a classe AutenticacaoPK.class e adicionei a anotação `@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"codEmpresa", "codUsuario"}))`, que criou a constraint UNIQUE para chaves codEmpresa e codUsuario. Também criei um atributo pra ser a PK da entity.

Dessa forma, não consigo inserir um token pra um mesmo codUsuario com mesmo codEmpresa.

Comment: Você tentou utilizar `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` ao invés de `@JoinColumn` em sua estratégia original? Qual versão do HIbernate?